# Alias don't function Ubuntu Mate 19.04

Tags: mate, 19.04, alias

I setup an alias on my Ubuntu Mate 19.04 like this,

```
alias up='apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'
```

I've setup the alias at the end of the file ***bash.bashrc***, using these commands,

```
nano /etc/bash.bashrc
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

But when I try to use `sudo up "command/alias"`, it returns an error,

```
sudo up: commmand not found
```

If I run only `up`, I get this error,

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I've put the `sudo` on the alias according the recommendation @steeldriver, like this:

```
alias up='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'
```

But then I've got this message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

It is asking me if I am root. But when I run `up` Ubuntu ask for the `sudo` password. Then I deduce I am at root.

Comment: Thanks! I will do know. Thanks

Comment: I solved partialy using sudo su

Comment: alternatively you could use `alias up='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'`

Comment: ok, thanks. doing alias up='sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade' i'm receiving the error message that i put above thanks anyway

Comment: **both** commands should be preceded by `sudo`

Comment: Know is really SOLVED! Both commands with sudo

alias up='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Thanks!